# AutoMapper in a class library

Tags: automapper

I create a class library to put my repositories, domain model and my DTO.
When a user call ClienteRepository.GetById(1) for exemple, it should get the Client domain model and transform into a ClientDTO to return this, example:

```
public class ClientRepository{
     public ClientDTO GetById(int id){
          var clientDto = Mapper.Map<Client, ClientDTO>(_db.Client.Find(id));

          return clientDto;
     }

}
```

the problem is that Mapper.Map doesn't work because I did not create the map (`Mapper.CreateMap<Client, ClientDTO>()`).

My question: How can I do this in a class library if I dont have global.asax to create it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved my problem using https://github.com/davidebbo/WebActivator. Just create a new class and put this code:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof (MapsInit), "Activate")]
namespace Database
{
    public static class MapsInit
    {
        public static void Activate()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<ClienteDto, Cliente>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Cliente, ClienteDto>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It really saved my time, straightforward solution!

Comment: Does WebActivator works inside the Class library project also ? please share.

Comment: When i try to create a class like this. It throws the runtime error in CSC compiler due to the persence of System.Web assembly in the class library project.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need a Global.asax for Automapper.
It's just the better way to do mapping init for a web project.

Just put your init code in a static constructor

```
 static MyStaticCtor()
    {
        //samples
        //Mapper.CreateMap<AccountViewModel, Account>();
        //Mapper.CreateMap<AccountSettingViewModel, AccountSetting>()

        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
```

or even, you can simply do this in the constructor of your Repository.

Comment: But my solution has several projects each one with your responsability; now If I put all maps in one web project, I would have to do the map for every web project that uses one project. And yes, I can put in my repository but then I would repeat lots of maps.

Comment: I have a class library called X(for example) that uses automapper and I have three asp.net mvc projects that uses X. I dont want to create the code 'Mapper.CreateMap' in every asp.net mvc project.

Comment: so, put the createmap in X. What is the problem ?

Comment: The problem is I dont know when to put. I think repositories shouldn't know about maps, it's just not their responsability. I'm looking for something like https://github.com/davidebbo/WebActivator that pre compile some code.